Web Scraping - Error "Unable to locate element" haciendo login en una página Web
Hola soy nuevo programando en Python y he estado haciendo web scraping con algunas URL y me han funcionado sin ningún problema, pero hay una página en especifico que no me toma los parámetros de inicio de sesión "usuario", "contraseña" y botón de "login". Dejo el código que estoy usando para ver si es que hay algo que estoy pasando por alto o si será la extracción de los XPATH de esa pagina lo que no me está funcionando.
Para la extracción de los XPATH en la página doy click derecho + Inspeccionar y con el selector me ubico en cada casilla que requiero conseguir su XPATH.
NOTA: solo me pasa con una página en especifico, las demás me funciona correctamente.
url = "url de la pagina"
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="username"]').click()
time.sleep(2)
username_field = driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="username"]')
username_field.send_keys("xxxxxxx")
time.sleep(1)
password_field = driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="j_passWord"]')
password_field.send_keys("xxxxxx")
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element("xpath", "//input[@value='Inicio de sesión']").click()
time.sleep(10)
screenshot = driver.save_screenshot('C:/Users/Jose/Downloads/screenshots/captura_APM.png')
time.sleep(1)
driver.quit()


Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Jose\Desktop\Monitoring_Bot\commands\captura_APM.py", line 31, in <module>
    driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="username"]').click()
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Jose\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 748, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {"using": by, "value": value})["value"]
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Jose\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 354, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Jose\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="username"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=130.0.6723.70); For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception


Hola, sin poder reproducir el código y sin acceso a la web es muy complicado depurar estos errores para dar con la causa concreta que es muy variable.No obstante, la causa más común es que el elemento no esté visible aún en el DOM cuando procedes a su búsqueda. No es recomendable que uses time.sleep para las esperas, usa los tiempos de espera implícitos o explícitos que provee selenium. Por ejemplo, usa un tiempo de espera explícito con una condición de espera adecuada y establece el timeout en un valor alto de principio

Hola muchas gracias... voy a probar y vuelvo a comentar!!!

Como comenta FJSevilla, si no podemos reproducir el error, solo podemos ofrecerte posibles causas. Una de ellas podría ser que el elemento que intentas localizar esté dentro de un iframe. En ese caso, primero deberías indicarle a Selenium que seleccione dicho iframe antes de buscar el elemento que necesitas. El método switch_to.frame() de Selenium, permite cambiar el contexto al del iframe

No me funciono con los tiempos explicitos, pero lo logre resolver con el modulo pyautogui lanzando comandos de teclado, aqui dejo el codigo, disculpen si no esta muy pro pero soy nuevo en esto.
        url = "pagina web" # URL que deseas capturar

        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
        options.add_argument('--window-size=1024,720}')
        #options.add_argument('--headless')
        options.add_argument("--hide-scrollbars")
        options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
        options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
        options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
        options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\Jose\\Application Data")
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
        driver.maximize_window()
        driver.get(url)
        time.sleep(2)
        pyautogui.press('tab')
        time.sleep(1)
        pyautogui.press('tab')
        time.sleep(1)
        pyautogui.press('tab')
        time.sleep(1)
        pyautogui.press('tab')
        time.sleep(1)
        pyautogui.press('tab')
        time.sleep(1)
        pyautogui.write("xxxxxx") #usuario
        time.sleep(1)
        pyautogui.press('tab')
        time.sleep(1)
        pyautogui.write("xxxxx") #contraseña
        time.sleep(1)
        pyautogui.press('enter')
        time.sleep(25)
        screenshot = driver.save_screenshot('C:/Users/Jose/Downloads/screenshots/captura_APM.png')
        driver.quit()

